# React - Why can I use React's methods without calling super?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wonder, how is it possible that a component can use reacts methods, such as render, componentDidMount etc. if calling the constructor with super is not mandatory? Shouldn't it be that a component inherits the methods of its Parent class (which is React since I'm extending it) and calling super to use them?
Thanks!

Comment: Those methods don't event exist in the parent component they specifically exist for you to perform logic (excluding the constructor)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. As far as I know, extending a class means the child class inherits the parent class non-private methods and properties.

Comment: Im asking - if (unless I misunderstand it) we can use reacts methods such as render etc, because we inherit them. When we inherit them, I wonder how can we inherit them without calling super.

Comment: My answer is pointing out that `super()` is absolutely not mandatory for a class to inheritate methods or properties. I dont know where you picked that up. super() is just a tool in case you need to use the base class constructor. React uses super to pass props to child components. However you may have child components without props

Comment: We do not inherit from components in the app. We use props and higher-order-components to extend and configure functionality. We inherit directly from React's Component/PureComponent which do not have code to execute in the methods you mentioned except for constructor. So what are you asking, be more specific, maybe give a use case?

Comment: Im not talking about inheritance of methods of other components. I am more talking about how we 'get enabled' to use for instance render method. we are by extending React.Component. So basically as I understand every component is a child of React.Component. If thats how it is, why dont we need to call super? Thats mandatory for each class that extends another one normally.

Comment: I said so twice already. `super()` IS NOT mandatory for inheritance. Its only for "specific" cases. Please read up on inheritance. (super() is found in Java as well as C# in a little different way)

Comment: if I have a simple parent and child class(pure js), I get an error (saying that i must call super) if I try to call the parents class from the child, so Im not sure what you mean!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ns3q5t91/ You must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't specific enough about what *calling super* refers to, while it can mean two different things.

`super()` refers to parent constructor call. It is necessary only in child constructor. It is mandatory in child constructor once it's used, this is required by ES6 specification:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // if no super() is called, it's invalid ES6 class 
  }

  render() {...}
}
```

But the constructor itself isn't mandatory (so-called implicit constructor):

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {};

  // is a shortcut for:
  /*
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }
  */

  render() {...};
}
```

`super.method` refers to `method` property on parent class prototype. It can be used in child constructor and prototype methods. Its use is optional.

Child class can override a method entirely without using respective `super` method:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render () { return 'foo'; }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  render () { return 'bar'; }
}
```

Or augment its functionality:

```
class AnotherChild extends Parent {
  render () { return <h1>{super.render()}</h1>; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`super()` will populate the base class (in your case React.Component) constructor with whatever you pass it.

Extending a class will inherit properties and methods.

You may absolutely extend a class without using its constructor. Thus never calling `super()`.

As for `super()` and react, if you are making use of props you will need to pass them down to the base class.